# I would like to dynamically show or hide a SliverAppBar

Tags: flutter

Currently, my code looks like this:

```
void main() {
  runApp(ProviderScope(child: MyApp()));
}

class MainScreen extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  late ScrollController controller;
  MainScreen({super.key, required this.controller});

  @override
  ConsumerState<ConsumerStatefulWidget> createState() => _MainScreenState();
}

class _MainScreenState extends ConsumerState<MainScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    widget.controller = ScrollController()..addListener(scrollControllerEvent);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    widget.controller.dispose();
    widget.controller.removeListener(() {});
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final poketmonPageIndex = ref.watch(poketmonPaginationProvider);
    final poketmonsProviderRef =
        ref.watch(poketmonsProvider(poketmonPageIndex));
    return ListView.builder(
      controller: widget.controller,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return PoketmonTile(poketmon: poketmonsProviderRef[index]);
      },
      itemCount: poketmonsProviderRef.length,
    );
  }

  void scrollControllerEvent() {
    // widget.controller.notifyListeners();
    final srcollProvider = ref.read(scrollDirectionProvider.notifier);
    if (widget.controller.offset >=
            widget.controller.position.maxScrollExtent &&
        !widget.controller.position.outOfRange) {
      ref.read(poketmonPaginationProvider.notifier).state++;
    }

    if (widget.controller.position.userScrollDirection ==
        ScrollDirection.reverse) {
      srcollProvider.state = false;
    }

    if (widget.controller.position.userScrollDirection ==
        ScrollDirection.forward) {
      srcollProvider.state = true;
    }
  }
}

class MyApp extends ConsumerWidget {
  MyApp({super.key});

  final ScrollController controller = ScrollController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        fontFamily: 'NotoSansKR',
        brightness: Brightness.light,
        primaryColor: Colors.white,
        appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          titleTextStyle: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.black,
            fontSize: 16,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: NestedScrollView(
          floatHeaderSlivers: true,
          controller: controller,
          headerSliverBuilder: (context, innerBoxIsScrolled) {
            log("innerbox scrolled => $innerBoxIsScrolled");
            return [
              Consumer(builder: ((context, ref, child) {
                // log(appbarVisible.toString());
                return const SliverAppBar(
                  title: Text("HELLOWORLD"),
                  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                  floating: true,
                  elevation: 0,
                );
              }))
            ];
          },
          body: MainScreen(
            controller: controller,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I want to make the SliverAppBar visible or invisible depending on the movement of the scrollController declared in the body of NestedScrollView. How can I do this?

I need to adjust the value of innerBoxIsScrolled in headerSliverBuilder to show or hide the SliverAppBar based on the movement of the scrollController in the body of the NestedScrollView. However, since I am still new to Flutter, I am not sure how to approach this.

[image]

> this picture is gif. please click the image more detail

As in the example above, I want the appbar to be hidden or visible when scrolling, but it is not.

Comment: kindly Attach image or video to understand what you exactly want

Comment: thanks @MobinAnsar I modified my ask

Comment: you want something like this https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kwc7c86NzW8kXfGOzKofd7DiAUyE6gD2/view

Comment: i want to hide the appbar when i scroll down but in my case dosen't work netstedscrollview scrollcontroller because inner listview(MainScreen in my case) scroll down perhapse